# Intellij Accessing file from hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, intellij-idea

As part of my intellij environment set up I need to connect to a remote hadoop cluster and access the files in my local spark code.

Is there any way to connect to hadoop remote environment without creating hadoop local instance?

A connection code snippet would be the ideal answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a keytab file to authenticate to the cluster, this is one way I've done it:

```
val conf: Configuration: = new Configuration()
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos")
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf)
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("user-name", "path/to/keytab/on/local/machine")
FileSystem.get(conf)
```

I believe to do this, you might also need some configuration xml docs. Namely `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, and `mapred-site.xml`. These are somewhere usually under `/etc/hadoop/conf/`.

You would put those under a directory in your program and mark it as Resources directory in IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks it worked..intellij had access to all xml files ...so conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos")
 was enough..